# Timezone trouble in MariaDB-10.0

Tags: 14.04, lts, mariadb, timezone

I'm currently running in a problem while using `mariadb-10.0`. After importing my local times using `mysql_tzinfo_to_sql` (as described [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mysql_tzinfo_to_sql/)) and adding `default_time_zone = UTC` to the `[mysqld]` section of my `/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf` my error.log tells me the following.

```
161004 12:15:57 [ERROR] Fatal error: Illegal or unknown default time zone 'UTC'
161004 12:15:57 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
161004 12:15:57 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
161004 12:15:57 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
161004 12:15:57 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
161004 12:15:57 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
161004 12:15:57 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
161004 12:15:57 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
161004 12:15:57 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 2.5G
161004 12:15:57 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
161004 12:15:58 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
161004 12:15:58 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
161004 12:15:58 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
161004 12:15:58 [Note] InnoDB:  Percona XtraDB (http://www.percona.com) 5.6.31-77.0 started; log sequence number 43378228606
161004 12:15:58 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
161004 12:15:58 [ERROR] Fatal error: Illegal or unknown default time zone 'UTC'
```

Checking the my `mysql_tzinfo_to_sql` the following would be imported:

```
INSERT INTO time_zone (Use_leap_seconds) VALUES ('N');
SET @time_zone_id= LAST_INSERT_ID();
INSERT INTO time_zone_name (Name, Time_zone_id) VALUES ('UTC', @time_zone_id);
INSERT INTO time_zone_transition_type (Time_zone_id, Transition_type_id, Offset, Is_DST, Abbreviation) VALUES
 (@time_zone_id, 0, 0, 0, 'UTC')
;
```

The time_zone_name tables looks correct so far:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> select * from mysql.time_zone_name where name like '%UTC%';
+---------------+--------------+
| Name          | Time_zone_id |
+---------------+--------------+
| Etc/UTC       |          418 |
| UTC           |          597 |
| posix/Etc/UTC |         1020 |
| posix/UTC     |         1199 |
| right/Etc/UTC |         1622 |
| right/UTC     |         1801 |
+---------------+--------------+
```